# IJCADでMdiActiveDocumentを実行すると止まってしまう

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

IJCAD2015でVB.Netを使って開発をしています。

IJCADで開いているドキュメントの中から特定のドキュメントをアクティブにするコードを作成してみました。ステップ実行したところ、MdiActiveDocumentで止まってしまいます。何が原因でしょうか？

```
Public Shared Function SetActiveDocument(ByVal docName As String) As Boolean

    Dim docMan As DocumentCollection = Application.DocumentManager

    For Each doc As Document In docMan

        If doc.Name.ToUpper = docName.ToUpper Then
            '''↓ここで止まってしまいます
            docMan.MdiActiveDocument = doc
            Return True
        End If

    Next

    Return False

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

おそらくですが、Functionを呼び出すコマンドでCommandFlags.SessionにCommandFlags.Modalが設定されていると思われますので、CommandFlags.Sessionをセットすれば解決する可能性が高いです。

前者は「ドキュメント実行コンテキスト」、後者は「アプリケーション実行コンテキスト」での実行となります。